# Derivation of (Shannon) entropy in the canonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

I am studying Statistical Mechanics and I cannot understand how to find the formula for the entropy $$ S = -k_B\sum_n p(n) \ln p(n) $$ which coincides with the Shannon entropy.

I have red many books and bibliography on the subject. The one I like more are the [lectures of David Tong](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/sp.pdf). In page 22 he says to consider a huge number of copies of the system+reservoir (so this copies form a microcanonical ensemble) and to use this in conjunction with the definition of entropy $ S = -k_B \ln \Omega $. What I don't understand is what is the $ \Omega $ that he calculates, i.e. what is  $$ \Omega = \frac{W!}{\prod_n (p(n)W)!} $$

I appreciate any help, be it an explanation or some alternative bibliography on the subject.

Comment: It is clearly stated in the text: "We must only figure out how
many ways there are of putting $p(n)W$ systems into state $n$ for each $n$. That’s a simple combinatoric problem: the answer is $\Omega=\dots$" What is exactly that you don't understand here?

Comment: You may find the [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) useful in seeing where the expression comes from

Comment: You realise, I expect, that $p(n)W$ is the number of systems in the $n^\text{th}$ state in the ensemble of $W$ systems? [I'm slightly surprised that this is about a $micro$canonical ensemble, but I don't have access to Tong.]

Comment: @PhilipWood You can access the pdf from the [link given by OP](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/sp.pdf).